# iphone app 3G upload image fail (wifi ok)

Tags: iphone, wwan

we try to upload image from iphone app to php script.
on wifi connection, things work smoothly.
but in 3G connection, it fails about 50% of time. (our 3G is very stable)
we have seen a few comments in other threads, but can't seem to get it work. 
anyone can provide some advice?

```
[asirequest setData:imageData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[name objectAtIndex:0]] andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"filedata"];
```

we tried to limit 3G bandwidth:

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES];
```

but the upload becomes very slow. and still it fails about 50% of time.
in wifi, the upload takes less than 10 second, and always work.

thx in a million.